# Downloading Multiple Files From the Items in Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried figuring out the following issue but I am not able to do it as I just started programming a month ago.

I have a listbox of 20 items:

```
private void loadDownloadXMLListBox()
{
    var items = new[] { "BARC", "DEV", "DOM", "EZJ", "GFS", 
                        "IHG", "JD.", "LAD", "LLOY", "MRW", 
                        "NXT", "OCDO", "RBS", "SMWH", "SPD", 
                        "STAN", "SYR", "TALK", "TSCO", "WMH" };
    foreach (var item in items) listDownloadXML.Items.Add(item);

    listDownloadXML.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

This is my code for downloading a single selected file from a website:

```
private void btnDownloadXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile("http://www.lse.co.uk/chat/" + listDownloadXML.SelectedItem,
                                                    @"..\..\sharePriceXML\" +
                                         listDownloadXML.SelectedItem + ".xml");
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Download Completed! File has been placed in the folder sharePriceXML!");
}
```

I want to click on a button "Download All" then, all the 20 items from the website will be downloaded. May I know how can I loop through the 20 items in the listbox and download them all into a folder without selecting item(s)? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in listDownloadXML.Items)
{
    //... your code to download "item".
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start by externalizing the download a single file functionality into a separate, reusable method:

```
public void DownloadFile(string item)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(
             "http://www.lse.co.uk/chat/" + item,
             @"..\..\sharePriceXML\" + item + ".xml"
        );
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Download Completed! File has been placed in the folder sharePriceXML!");
}
```

and then:

```
private void btnDownloadXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DownloadFile((string)listDownloadXML.SelectedItem);
}
```

and now to your question about multiple files => you use a loop and call the `DownloadFile` method for each element in the listbox:

```
foreach (string item in listDownloadXML.Items)
{
    DownloadFile(item);
}
```